# Removing a macro with doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have the following function:

```
void MYMACROTOEXPORTFUNCTION function1()
```

how do I instruct doxygen to remove the "MYMACROTOEXPORTFUNCTION" part from the documentation and prevent it from being shown? I already used "@cond ... @endcond" without success

Comment: See question 4 in the [FAQ](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/faq.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows (sample based on doxywizard)
[image]